# Get translational component of particular matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say I have a $4\times4$ rotation matrix $R$ and $4\times4$ translation matrix $T.$ If I multiply the matrices in this order $T * R$, the translation component of $T$ will not get affected. But if multiply them in order $R * T$, it will get affected by rotation values of $R$.

How can I describe the positional vector of the resulting matrix from $R * T$ multiplication, in terms of the rotational components of $R$ and the translation component of matrix $T?$ Can I describe it as the dot product of respective orientation component of matrix $R$ and the translation component of matrix $T?$

Comment: Please expand on what it means for $T$ to be a translation matrix. Translations have no fixed points, but each matrix, being a linear transformation, must leave $0$ fixed. Are you using homogeneous coordinates? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)#Matrix_representation

Comment: @Leo I would assume so; using homogeneous coordinates in this way is pretty standard for computer science.  Also, I suspect that the "dot-product" he's referring to is simply matrix-multiplication.

Comment: @Lenny It would be helpful if you could verify whether or not my suspicions are correct

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes I'm using homogenous coordinates. By translation matrix I mean identity matrix except the first three values in fourth column that describe translation (So matrix that has no rotation or scale). By rotation matrix I mean matrix that has zero translation. Dot product I'm referring to is the dot product between two three-dimensional vectors.

Comment: @LennyWhite I see. What exactly is the "orientation component" of the matrix $R$ then?  Is that the (directed) axis of rotation?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom By orientation components I basically meant the Forward, Right and Up vectors in matrix that describe an object's orientation.

Comment: @Lenny I see, basically the [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) of your rotation if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, that's right.

Comment: If I understood your verbal description correctly, then translating by the vector $\mathbf v$ before rotating by the matrix $\mathbf R$ (with an arbitrary axis-angle) is just the same as rotating by $\mathbf R$ before translating by the vector $\mathbf R\mathbf v$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mathematical description of what's going on that I hope you find helpful.

Let $[x]$ denote the "homogeneous coordinates" of $x$ (that is, if $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$, then $[x] = (x_1,x_2,x_3,1)$).  Suppose $T$ is defined to be a translation by the vector $b = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$, and that 
$$
R = \pmatrix{Q & 0_{3 \times 1}\\0 & 1}
$$
where $Q$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix.  Then $T$ and $R$ are defined so that
$$
T*[x] = [x + b], \qquad R*[x] = [Qx]
$$
The consequences of applying $R$ then $T$ are clear:
$$
T*R*[x] = T*[Qx] = [Qx + b]
$$
As expected, we have the rotation $Q$ followed by a translation by $b$. On the other hand, if we apply $T$ then $R$, we have
$$
R*T*[x] = R*[x + b] = [Q(x+b)] = [Qx + Qb].
$$
In other words, the net effect can be described as the same rotation $Q$ (or $R$ if you prefer) followed by a translation by the vector $Qb$.

You might find the following helpful. In terms of $T$ and $R$, you can access the offset $Qb$ using the fact that
$$
[Qb] = R*T*[\mathbf 0] = R*[b]
$$
where $\mathbf 0$ is $(0,0,0)$.